# how can i write to one csv file fast?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to repartition(1) the dataframe when writing to csv but it is running for more than 2 hours..i tried **repartition(20)** but it still very slow. I think the data is big and I am new to spark, how can I make this faster?

```
df.repartition(20).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(filepath)
```

Comment: [1] Try persisting the data frame before you write it and [2] if you reducing run a coalesce(1) instead of repartition(1)

Comment: provide your cluster information regarding nodes, datanodes, cores, memory etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in it on you local machine or remotely ?
Is it standalone/yarn cluster ,how many machines you have.

You can check in the Spark UI for the task see how many partitions are ?
Per machine you should have minimum 3*4 partitions - maxcan go upto 10000

Rather than repartition do coalesce(1) for just one partiton,it will cause less shuffle and job will e fast.
repartition causes more shuffle.